# How do I check if a function is being called by a method?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, mocking

How do I check if a function b() is being called by a method?

```
class hello():
    delete():
        b()
```

I want to use mock in a unit test.

Comment: What are your constraints? Can you modify `b`? Or monkeypatch it? Are you in fact asking aboud [coverage](https://docs.python.org/devguide/coverage.html)?

Comment: I can't modify b, I just need to check to see if its called when hello() is called with specific arguments.

Comment: Have you read through the [unittest.mock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html) documentation to see how to go about doing this? There are also several examples on how to mock methods and check if they are being called. If you have attempted this already, please share your code to help guide you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a test environment you can in fire up the python(or the Ipython) shell and use the debugger to call the function:

if this is your function

```
def multiplier(a,b):
    print a*b
```

then you can do this in the shell and debug the code:

```
import ipdb
ipdb.runcall(multiplier, 10, 10)
```